# same date can be selected with time difference only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetimepicker

I have 2 date and time selection box, as start date and end date. now i am able to select different dates with time. So what i want that can be able to select same date with time difference.
E.g
start date - 2020-07-02 time - 21:90
End date - 2020-07-02 time - 22:00

also i can be able to select start time from the current time with step of 30 minutes and the previous time is disable.

[image]

Tried code

```
 import Datetime from 'react-datetime';
    import momentLocalizer from 'react-widgets-moment';
    import { DateTimePicker } from 'react-widgets';
    import moment from 'moment';
```

start date

```
<Datetime
dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
timeFormat={false}
closeOnSelect={true}
onChange={(e) => {
    // changeStartDate(e);
    setStartDate(e);
}}
value={date}
isValidDate={ validStartDate }
```

/>

start time

```
    <DateTimePicker
    date={false}
    timeFormat={'HH:mm'}
    format={'HH:mm'}
    // defaultValue={new Date(startInterval)}
    onChange={(e) => {
        setStartTime(e);
    }}
    value={time}
    inputProps={{component: props => <input {...props} readOnly/>}}
    // min={new Date()}
    // step={30}
    // min={ (date && moment(date).isSame(moment(), 'day')) ? moment(new Date()).add({hours: 6}).set({minute:0}).toDate() : moment().startOf('day').toDate() }
/>
```

**similar code is for the end date and time also.**

function which is checking for valid date

```
var yesterday = Datetime.moment().subtract(1, 'day');
var validStartDate = function( current ){
  if(endDate){
    return !current.isAfter( Datetime.moment(endDate).add(0, 'day') ) && current.isAfter( yesterday );
  }else{
    return current.isAfter( yesterday );
  }
};
var validEndDate = function( current ){
  if(date){
    return current.isAfter( Datetime.moment(date).add(-1, 'day') );
  }
  else{
    return current.isAfter( yesterday );
  }
};
```

output : a button should be enable on the basis of correct input, which is not happening.

Comment: You have to validate everything  at the end before you filter or save (or whatever you're doing).  You can't set parameters on the controls in advance if you don't know what all the parameters are.

Comment: @JohnLord pardon me, but i didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i need to answer my own question.

changed start time to

```
<DateTimePicker
date={false}
open={openStartTime}
timeFormat={'HH:mm'}
format={'HH:mm'}
onChange={(e) => {
    setStartTime(e);
}}
value={time}
min={new Date(new Date().getTime()+ (1000 * 60 * 30) - (new Date().getTime() % 
(1000 * 60 * 30)))}
/>
```

changed end time to

```
<DateTimePicker
date={false}
timeFormat={'HH:mm'}
format={'HH:mm'}
onChange={(e) => {
  setEndTime(e);
}}
value={endTime}
min={moment(endDate).isAfter(date) ? moment(endTime).startOf('day').toDate() : new Date(new Date(time).getTime()+ (1000 * 60 * 30) - (new Date(time).getTime() % (1000 * 60 * 30)))}
/>
```

and this solved my problem.

Comment: what i was saying is you need to control what order your fields are filled in.  This will break if someone fills out the end date first.

Comment: So that in my case i have already disabled the end date selection. So the selection must be the first date and then the end date. So it won't break.